# Binary Search trees - Far left node always contains the smallest value?

Tags: binary-search-tree

As mentioned in the title, is the far left node in a binary search tree always contains the smallest value?  In a search path, say A is the far left node, B is the parent node, and C is the far right node. Is there any example that the order a <= b <= c is not always the case?? I know that rotations can be made to ensure balance property is maintained, but I can't come up with an example where things are not always balanced such that a <= b <= c is not always true. I'm just learning this data structure, and it's definitely different to me as compared to arrays and lists. And yes, this is an exercise given to me. I'd just like some pointers/ideas!

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question is "Yes," however it should be qualified that this is based on the assumption that you are building your tree in the way typically taught in a data structures class.

What I mean is that if you are in fact determining whether to insert a node to the left or to the right based on whether the value in question is respectively less than or greater than the current node, then the answer is a definite yes.  Obviously, if you are using some other criteria to make your determination then this can change. :)  Because of this strategy, you can guarantee that there are no values greater than the parent node down the left path.

This is actually where the tremendous power of a binary tree comes in.  It does mean, however, that if the data being inserted is poorly distributed you can end up with a tree that is heavily skewed in one direction or another.  This is a problem because part of the purpose of a tree of this sort is to trade off insertion time against search time.  If the tree is skewed, there is no great benefit and, in fact, it can take longer to find a node than it might in a flat array.

This leads you to the discussion of balanced trees and AVL trees.  In order to guarantee a worst case specific Big O value for any search, the tree is rebalanced each time an insertion will result in the number of nodes to the left and right getting too far out of balance.  While this adds more overhead to inserts and deletes, the guaranteed worst case is well worth it when you have large amounts of data.

Hope you have fun!  Data Structures is a fascinating and interesting course of study!